# moving anchor points a tags with ids and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a long vertical parallax website.

The mobile version of the site is slightly different but it shares the same nav using the same anchor points.

I'm trying to add ids to the anchor tags -- so that way I can move them with css under mobile resolutions.

```
<a id="anchor1" href="#anchor1"></a>
```

But it isn't being read -- any suggestions?

```
@media(max-width:700px) and (min-width:100px) { 

    a#anchor1 { margin-top:-110px; position:absolute;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the screen part and I would find another way to get the element rather than id's, either a[href="#"] or put classes on the anchors otherwise you will have to write the code out loads of time depending on how many links you have.

```
@media screen and (max-width:700px) and (min-width:100px) { 

a#anchor1 { margin-top:-110px; position:absolute;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Margin will be ignored for inline elements. Add display:inline-block to your css and you should be good